# How to run the Tableau workbook with .hyper extracts in Tableau Online?

Tags: tableau-api

I am familiar with Tableau dev and developed a report that uses 2 .hyper extracts and one Excel file and it is running fine with correct data. This is from Dev environment.

But client need to run from Tableau Online, now I am not aware (in fact no knowledge) on how run a workbook on tableau online with this setup.

I am trying to get answers to the below points:

1. How to refresh Tableau .hyper extracts?
2. How to specify Excel location (to pick new one every time workbook is refreshed)
3. Refresh Tableau workbook to show new data every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Tableau Online cannot reach files on a local network.

> Tableau Online in the cloud cannot reach data sources that you
>   maintain on your local network. Depending on the connection, you might
>   be required to publish an extract and set up a refresh schedule using
>   Tableau Bridge. Source:
>   https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_datasources_about.htm

If by "Online" you mean Tableau Server, then there is a way to refresh the data from an Excel data source. Please, check this official link: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/automatically-updating-data-in-server-workbook-that-uses-live-connection-to-excel

Could you give more details about your extracts? If your hyper extracts are from a published datasource, then you can refresh them easily. You just need to create a schedule for the workbook, after publishing it. It is necessary to "allow refresh access" like shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for wishing and reply, I have 2 hyper extracts connected to oracle database and one excel file (Not extract), My task is to schedule the .hyper extracts and excel file will be replaced weekly from a location, so need to comfigure that, Please help.

Comment: I have uploaded the workbook without success as when I uploaded workbook and went to datasource tab in tableau online the I am able to see `No Authentication` on the extracts

Comment: I am not aware of the process to publish, please guide me as my client want it to publish and refresh on tableau online

Comment: Hi. When you publish the workbook to the Server, you can include the datasources (hyper extracts). And you can choose whether to publish them with the credentials saved or not. You can change this later, on the Server side. On the Server you go to the workbook, click on it to see its details, and then you can manage the scheduling agenda. It is simple to schedule a extract refresh as there are agendas previously created by Tableau and you just need to choose one.

Comment: Please, check the following official link for a few more details: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_workbooks_share.htm

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I published the workbook nothing prompted for credentials and when I scheduled nothing refreshes

Comment: But my datasource is a combination of 2 hyper extracts and one excel sheet, will this work if I directly publish the extract from workbook?

Comment: Hi. You can publish the 3 datasources. As I mentioned before, you need to follow the instructions (link on my answer) to update the Excel file with live connection (Tableau Server). If you publish it to Tableau Online, then you will need Tableau Bridge in order to update the Excel data.

Comment: When I read your explanation, eveything looks clear but when I start working nothing works

Comment: Few question, if I publish individual datasources then how do I connect those datasources to tableau workbook in tableau online also tried bridge connection still nothing refreshes, what am I missing? I am unable to connect dots

Comment: Hi again. When you publish the workbook (via Tableau Desktop) you have the option to embed the datasource or to publish it separately, If you choose to publish it separately, then it will become a Tableau Server datasource and you will be able to connect other workbooks to it. When you choose to publish the datasource separately, then it will automatically be a live connection between the workbook and the datasource. Anyway, you will need to schedule an update for the workbook and or datasources.

Comment: Did you schedule an extract refresh and it did not work? What steps did you take?

Comment: Thanks for followup, I have created a extract through tableau data prep and just found extract from tableau prep will be a static one and can't be refreshed, so I am in deep trouble, need to create a new extract from tableau desktop now, Can you please help on how to schedule the extract created from tableau desktop

Comment: Thanks for your info, I have managed to upload the workbook, first uploaded the dataasource as extract (that has 2 .hyper and one excel) then scheduled through bridge client. successfully able to refresh the excel part but oracle .hyper extracts are not refreshing, am I missing some thing? also everytime full refresh is enabled how to enable incremental refresh. can you please guide thanks

Comment: @itsantos, can you please help me with this question        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826927/hyper-extract-is-not-refreshing-from-tableau-desktop

Comment: Hi, Siva. How are you? Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. It's been a busy week. Could you, please, explain the steps you took for publishing these extracts? As per my understanding, you can schedule a extract refresh during the publishing or after. On Tableau Online you should navigate to the data sources folder, click on the data source which you want to update and go to the 'extract refreshes' tab and create a new Tableau Bridge refresh schedule. You can also change an existing refresh schedule. During this process you can choose whether you need a full or incremental refresh.

Comment: @Itsantos, thanks for reply, sorry for late reply. My problem is when I publish workbook all 3 extracts are published along with it, but I need the workbook need to take the published individual extracts, in this case what is the process, can you please help